# Array map on arrays not updating array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays

```
[
  [1,3,5,7,8,8],
  [1,3,5,7,8,8],
  [1,3,5,7,8,8],
  [1,3,5,7,8,8],
  [1,3,5,7,8,8]
]
```

I am trying to insert a value between each item. So I have this:

```js
let reelList = [
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8]
]

reelList.map(reel => {
  // Adds the separator (works)
  let v = separate(reel, '-')
  console.log(v)
  return v
})

function separate(arr, value) {
  return arr.reduce((result, element, index, array) => {
    result.push(element)
    index < array.length - 1 && result.push(value)
    return result
  }, []);
}

// Logs the new list to the console (doesn't work)
console.log(reelList)
```

When I log the values after I run the `separate` function they are separated, however, when I display `reelList` they are not separated. Why is that?

Comment: `map` doesn't alter the array, it returns a new one (like `String#replace`).

Comment: They are two different arrays. The one of reduce is the `[]` you passed as second argument to it and then added values to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map()` function returns a new array. It doesn't modify the existing one.

You would need to set the results of `reelList.map()` to something else.

```js
let reelList = [
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8]
]

const finalResult = reelList.map(reel => {
  // Adds the separator (works)
  let v = separate(reel, '-')
  console.log(v)
  return v
})

function separate(arr, value) {
  return arr.reduce((result, element, index, array) => {
    result.push(element)
    index < array.length - 1 && result.push(value)
    return result
  }, []);
}

// Logs the new list to the console (doesn't work)
console.log(finalResult);
```

If you want to edit the array in place, instead of using `map()`, use a `forEach()` with a callback that has a second and third parameter, which are index and array. Then you can update the array with the new values as you go.

```js
let reelList = [
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8],
  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8]
]

reelList.forEach((reel, index, arr) => {
  // Adds the separator (works)
  let v = separate(reel, '-')
  arr[index] = v;
  console.log(v)
})

function separate(arr, value) {
  return arr.reduce((result, element, index, array) => {
    result.push(element)
    index < array.length - 1 && result.push(value)
    return result
  }, []);
}

// Logs the new list to the console (doesn't work)
console.log(reelList);
```

Comment: While you generally want to avoid mutations of data, if your specific use-case does make sense to do it, you can use `forEach()`. I added an updated example.

Answer (score 0):

You could map a new array with a calculated lenght and take the result of the calculated index ot the dash.

```js
var array = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8], [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8]],
    result = array.map(a => Array.from({ length: a.length * 2 - 1 }, (_, i) => a[i / 2] || '-'));

console.log(result);
```